# How to add a caption to a image inside tabular

Tags: tables, captions

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}  
\begin{tabular}{c}
\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{%  change the parbox width as appropiate
\begin{itemize}
\item Master of Physics in Physics with Theoretical Physics
\item Relevant modules: Quantum Field Theory, Gauge Field Theories, Condensed Matter, Semiconductor Nanostructures.
\item Quantum foam as a possible mechanism for quantum gravity - topological underpinning
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabular} \hspace{1.5cm}
& \begin{tabular}{c}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6cm, width=4.5cm]{example_image} 
This is an example of a neutrino interaction
\end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}\end{document}
```

Hi, i was wondering how I could add a caption under the image in this example. When I try to use the caption functionality, it either doesn't show up If I place is in the corresponding tabular column, or it returns with an error. I've tried \captionof{figure}{text}, but the compile time is too long and I time out!

Comment: I was going to show a paracol solution, but it seems paracol and revtex4-2 (could not find 4-1) are not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using package `capt-of` or `caption` if you need more functionality.

I have used `\parbox`es instead of `tabular` because I think their functionality is better in this case.

But if you must use a tabular then I think useing a `p{...}` column or a `\parbox` in the column for the image would be necessary for the `\caption` to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or caption
\begin{document}
 
\noindent
\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{%  change the parbox width as appropiate
\begin{itemize}
\item Master of Physics in Physics with Theoretical Physics
\item Relevant modules: Quantum Field Theory, Gauge Field Theories, Condensed Matter, Semiconductor Nanostructures.
\item Quantum foam as a possible mechanism for quantum gravity - topological underpinning
\end{itemize}}%
\hspace{1.5cm}%
\parbox{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-1.5cm}{
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[height=6cm, width=4.5cm]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{This is an example of a neutrino interaction}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!